# What kind of error is when you run an infinite loop accidentally

Tags: c, compiler-errors, syntax-error, runtime-error, typeerror

Assumed a given code:

```
int n;

while (n<100){ n--;}
```

`n` isn't initialized. Therefore, what kind of error is it when you use an un-initialized variable?

As well, there is a chance that the loop would be infinite? In that case, is it a logical error or a run-time error?

(Generally, if accidentally there is an infinite loop in a certain code, is It a logical error or a rum-time error?).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `n` has whatever happens to be in that  memory location. Maybe the compiler optimizes away your loop. If it doesn't, the loop isn't infinite: if `n` happens to be positive, it will get under 100 and the loop stops. If `n` happens to be negative, it will reach the lowest possible value for int on your system, then overflow and become positive, and eventually get below 100.

Comment: [Undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/1505939)

Answer (score 1):

and generally, if there is an infinite loop, is it a run-time error or a logical error?
as well, if i use an un-initialized variable. is it a run time error or a compilation error?

Answer (score -1):

you do not get an error, you app simply decrements the counter for a while, and will move on when it overflows